# Vuex dispatch creates significant overhead

Tags: vue.js, vuex

Recently I noticed that dispatching a certain action takes way longer than it should, so I went to add some timers.

This is the action code:

```js
// ...
mutations: {
    setPrimary(state, data) {
        state.resources.primary = data
    }
},
// ...
actions: {
    async load({ commit }) {
        const start = performance.now()
        // ...
        const apiResult = await apiClient.get("/")
        const startCommit = performance.now()
        commit("setPrimary", apiResult)
        console.log(`commit finished in ${performance.now() - startCommit} ms`)
        console.log(`action finished in ${performance.now() - start} ms`)
    }
}
```

And the code dispatching the action:

```js
const start = performance.now()
await store.dispatch("load")
console.log(`dispatch finished in ${performance.now() - start} ms`)
```

Now the expected output would be that the timings are pretty close, but the opposite is the case:

```
action finished in 820
dispatch finished in 1365 ms
```

Which to me is quite confusing, since calling `dispatch` shouldn't add such massive overhead. So far I have no idea where it might come from.

Edit:

It turns out this is caused by the `commit` call. The delay disappers without this.
Timing the commit like so reveals that it only takes 1 ms to execute, which means that this somehow has side effects I am unaware of.

Comment: Is Vue devtools active? Can this be reproduced in production mode? *function body omitted for brevity* - that's the problem with the question. If you're able to reproduce it without this code then do this. Otherwise it's relevant and shouldn't be omitted.

Comment: @EstusFlask Vue devtools is active, but it can be reproduced in production mode. I don't see why the code would matter, since the timing happens right outside of the `dispatch` call and right where the action begins and ends. There shouldn't be such a significant difference, no matter what code gets executed in between, unless there's a huge misunderstandingfrom my side.

Comment: Vue devtools should be inactive by default in prod, isn't it? Try with Vue devtools being inactive, so you're sure they don't cause a slowdown. It matters because it's unclear whether 800ms delay is justified or there's some sort of global slowdown. Vuex plugins can cause a delay, or there's some parallel process that occupies main thread, including Vue renderer. I wouldn't expect 550ms out of nowhere in that place.

Comment: I tried it with devtools disabled, the result was similar (smaller delay but still roughly double the time to execute `dispatch`. What I can't wrap my head around is how any significant delay there *could* be justified since both timers should time the execution time of the action. So if something *inside* the action is slow, that should also show in the timing results from inside the action. But that doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: I followed your hint that it could be something inside of the action and it turns out that there is a specific `commit` call that causes this delay. But I timed this call and it reports an execution time of only 1 ms. If I remove this call, no significant delay is measured. I still fail to see how function call that executes in 1 ms can cause a 500 ms delay.

Comment: *I still fail to see how function call that executes in 1 ms can cause a 500 ms delay* - try to remove everything from your app except these Vuex actions, this way you can figure out if it really can. It's likely that state.resources.primary update causes costly view update that blocks main thread. You can debug the performance of your app apart from Vuex to check for bottlenecks.

Answer (score -1):

The overhead comes from the fact that your action is an "asynchronous" function which means when the "interpreter" executes it, it will through it to a "browser API" to handle its execution instead of executing it directly in the "Stack", and wait for its result and after that, will get it back to the "queue" where the "Event loop" will wait for the stack to be empty and returns it with the results to the stack to continue execution